# Currently available cars (under $35K) with adaptive cruise-control and lane centering?

Tags: self-driving

Apologies if this is off topic for this site, but I couldn't find a relevant site on the Stack Exchange network for this question.

I'm going to buy a new car and I'd like one that can essentially drive itself on a highway without user input. My driving is essentially highway driving, and if the car can take over once I'm on the highway, this will make life so much easier. Specifically, I want the car to be able to adjust speeds to account for cars in front of me (adaptive cruise control) and stay in my lane even when the road turns (lane centering).

I know Tesla's newer cars do this, but they are currently quite expensive (until the Model 3 is out). Are there other cars on the market today that can do this, while also being affordable (say below $35K)?

Comment: As far as I know, Tesla's about the only game in town until Google gets their car on the road. I'm sure the rest of the manufacturers are working towards autonomous automobiles, but for now, you have to play Tesla's game. BTW, [Tesla's aren't infallible](http://fortune.com/2017/03/04/tesla-crash-footage-autopilot/) (though, the driver is at fault here for not paying attention).

Comment: Subaru (and doubtless many others by now) have adaptive cruise control and lane departure in their Eyesight system - but it won't drive for you, and gets easily confused if the road markings are not in good order. Available on all vehicles in their range, with most coming in below $35K.

Comment: @SolarMike:  You clearly don't read the press.  There are several proof of concept car hacks in the wild.

Comment: I'm basing my comment on the latest... But proof of concept does not mean it has actually happened, just that it is possible...

Comment: BTW, this is a great topic for the chat!

Answer (score 1):

Operating a motor vehicle is the most dangerous thing people do on a daily basis. In the US alone, 35,000 people die from this every single year, that's 3 times the murder rate.
So, look at your car, then look at your neighbourhood drug dealer wearing his pants halfway down to his knees with a 9mm semi-automatic handgun sticking out of his underwear. Your car is 3x more likely to kill you than he is. And here is why:

- ABS tried to kill me once (stupid rental car had summer tires and we had an unexpected blizzard and the ABS prevented the brakes from being applied AT ALL)
- people have died because their cruise control spun the car off the road in poor weather
- the onboard computer (on the same stupid rental) tried to kill me twice (one time, I was trying to clear an intersection on a changing traffic light and an oncoming car was driving erratically making me give the car confusing commands, i.e., hard on the gas, hard on the brakes, then hard on the gas again. The onboard computer must have thought I was having a stroke so it rev-limited the engine to 2000 rpms. Ever tried clearing an intersection on what is basically a high idle? The second time, the computer had a split second hesitation before kicking in the electronic power steering, I was travelling at 80 kph towards a concrete barrier at the time with a sharp left bend)
- people have driven off cliffs because the GPS told them to

Keep your hands on the wheel, keep your eyes on the road, keep your feet on the pedals, and keep the frigging electronics out of the car.

Comment: Could not agree more! As a software engineer, I know that no code is perfect. I wouldn't trust "lane centering" or "adaptive cruise control" to drive for me. They are designed to help distracted drivers not kill someone, not drive the car for extended periods of time.

Comment: However, there will come a time when the electronics and these type of systems will be much more safe and reliable than the human drivers.

Comment: @markb Only is EVERY SINGLE CAR has them. Electronics don't know what to do with an idiot at the wheel of another car.